# Testrpc installation on Ubuntu 14.04 is failing

Tags: testrpc, ethereumjs

I'm trying to install testrpc using the command

```
sudo npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

It's failing with the below error message. Can someone please help?

> sudo npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
>   npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.10.28
>   npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
>   npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
>   npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:298
>           [this, (next) => { computeMetadata(this.idealTree); next() }],
>                          ^
>   npm ERR! Unexpected token >
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /home/kumard/.npm/_logs/2017-06-25T18_34_19_267Z-debug.log

This is happening inspite of having a higher version of node

```
kumard@kumard-Lenovo-G580:~/.npm/_git-remotes$ node -v
v5.12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old version of node.

I'd suggest to use [Node Version Manager (nvm)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install a more recent version of node.

Comment: You mean higher than v5.12.0?

Comment: In your log it says `npm does not support Node.js v0.10.28`. Perhaps you have two versions installed and there's a conflict betweeen them. Also more recent version of node is 8.1.2, also a benefit of nvm is you do not need to use sudo.